# When a button is clicked I want to access the data of the rows which were checked by the user.I don't know how to loop through my mat-table rows

Tags: html, angular, typescript, mat-table

I want to loop through this column of my mat-table to find which rows are checked and then push that row data into an array.

```js
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="pushRowToArray($event, row)" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
    </mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make the checkbox call a function and add it to an array in there.

Like this:

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="matCheckBox" (change)="yourfunc($event)"/>
```

and make the func like

```
yourfunc(e) {
   if(e.target.checked){
      this.array.push(e.target);
   }else{
     this.array = this.array.filter(obj => obj !== e.target);
   }
}
```